# Returning a substring after a specified character

Tags: swift3

If I have a string, e.g. spider, how do you create a new string that starts at the first vowel and ends with the last character of the initial string.

For example:
 - spider would be ider 
 - elephant would be elephant
 - campus would be ampus

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution with a custom `CharacterSet` as `String` extension

```
extension String {

    func substringFromFirstVowel() -> String
    {
        let vowelCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiouAEIOU")
        guard let range = self.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowelCharacterSet) else { return self }
        return self.substring(from: range.lowerBound)
    }
}


"elephant".substringFromFirstVowel() // elephant
"spider".substringFromFirstVowel() // ider
"campus".substringFromFirstVowel() // ampus
```

Comment: Huh, faster than me with the exact same solution, even the function name is the same. The only difference is that I have used `options: .caseInsensitive`.

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks for the hint, but `.caseInsensitive` doesn't seem to consider the character set.

Comment: @vadiant Interesting. Another quirk of the `String` API...  I would probably use `[aeiou]` regular expression anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little function

```
func firstVowel(input : String) -> String {
    var firstVowel = true
    let vowels = "aAeEiIoOuU".characters
    var result = ""

    for char in input.characters {

        if(!firstVowel) {
            result.append(char)
        }

        if(vowels.contains(char) && firstVowel) {
            firstVowel = false
            result.append(char)
        }
    }
    return result
}

print(firstVowels(input: "elephant")) //prints elephant
print(firstVowels(input: "Spider")) //prints ider
```